# How can i turn the Boolean Equation pq+r into a switch circuit?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

How can I turn the Boolean Equation $pq+r$ into a switch circuit?
I have synthesized this and drawn the *NOR* gates circuit however I'm not sure how to go about drawing/constructing the switch circuit.

Answer (score 1):

two parallel branches one with switch r and in the other p and q in serie:

```
  ----/ r-----
=|            |==
  --/ p--/ q--
```